# Half-column width margin outside column in Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, padding

I have a div which takes 12 Bootstrap columns. How can I add margin of half of a column on right and half of a column on left?

Here is a starting point.

html:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12 takes12Columns">
    DIV WHICH TAKES 12 COLUMNS
  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.takes12Columns
{
  background: red;
  text-align: center;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1gpna1h5/.

Comment: I don't understand. The col-md-12 already has padding on the left/right sides of 15 px. If you want to add margins use `margin-left`, `margin-right`

Comment: @ZimSystem, sorry. I made a mistake. I meant margin, not padding. If you take look at the jsfiddle you will be able to get what I want. I want to start div after half of the column and end it before half of the column to the end.

Comment: @ZimSystem, where should I add the margin? To the row or to the col-md-12? I need not 15 px, but exactly half of the column. It will change dynamically on the resizing.

Comment: half of the column doesn't make sense dear

Comment: @recoverymen, for me it does. But I suspect, that there is no solution to my problem. I hope my suspicion is wrong.

Comment: @ZimSystem, yes, I am using the third one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do this with standard Bootstrap. You can create a custom build with 24 columns, or you can make a custom row class to add the margins that are equivalent to 1/2 a column unit of 8.33333%. Then subtract the normal negative margin of the `row`.

```
.row-custom {
  margin-left: calc(4.166666% - 15px);
  margin-right: calc(4.166666% - 15px);   
}
```

Also, `row` should always be placed inside `container`.

http://www.codeply.com/go/QFy6hVUVDc

Comment: Why row always should be inside container?

Comment: "Rows must be placed within a .container (fixed-width) or .container-fluid (full-width) for proper alignment and padding." __ http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Comment: Thanks for the attention.

Answer (score 0):

If you Using bootstrap you can use `container-fluid` or simple `container` class to make changes on side of columns in above case you can use `margin-right` or `margin-left` please see

[Js Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1gpna1h5/8/)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the attention. But it is not what I need. It doesn`t affect margin dynamically. Above is appropriate answer.